# Access 97 Frontend - SQL Server 2005 Backend Linked Table Error

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I have a legacy Access 97 Frontend application which utilises a SQL Server 2005 backend over a SQL Server ODBC Driver (Connection), we use the Linked Table feature on this setup.

I create, amend and link in tables on a daily basis and I am aware of the conversions that occur between the different data types.

There seems to be an issue with one table that I recently created, it has exactly the same setup and permissions as many of the other tables in the database but once I link it into Access 97 it seems to show #NAME in all columns and I also receive an '*ODBC Call Failed*' error.

If I remove the Primary Key from the table and do not select a 'Unique Record Identifier' then I am able to view the data in the table but I obviously can't edit it.

There are 3 columns which are VARCHAR's and are over 255, if I reduce these columns to 255 or less I am then able to view the data in the table but if I then try to edit or delete the data I receive a new error '*The Microsoft Jet Database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time*' - I know this is not possible because at present I am the only one with access to the table.

In this particular table there are 146 columns, if I delete half of these then the table starts to work as it should, again I have tables that have far more columns than this and work perfectly.

Comment: How many indexes are on the SQL server table?  I have seen issues when too many indexes are defined.

Comment: Just the one PK Clustered Index

Comment: when I see this, it's usually because of a PK/linked table key mismatch.  do your unique keys on the SQL side match the keys in the linked table's design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshooting issues like this can be frustrating for sure.

I have found this article very helpful for my linked tables:
[Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx)

Specifically read the section titled **Supporting Concurrency Checks**.
One thing you might try is adding a "timestamp" column to the table in question.

Comment: I have used the link provided and seems very helpful - the errors I am receiving when trying to open the table in Access are: 'DIAG [37000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Of'. (156) ' & 'DIAG [37000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' = ?'. (105) ' - Any ideas what could be causing this?